# how to access an NSObject variable from a structure in swift

Tags: swift, swift5

I have structure that consists of an a few variables.

```
struct Contact {
    var id:String = "Contact - \(UUID())"
    var fullname: String
    var exercises : [Exercise]
}
```

The part i am interest in is the `exercises` section. This variable takes the following class:

```
class Exercise : NSObject , NSSecureCoding{
    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true
    var excerciseName: String
    var excerciseReps: String
    var excerciseSets: String
    var excerciseWeights: String
    
    init(Name : String, Reps : String, Sets : String, Weights : String) {
        excerciseName = Name
        excerciseReps = Reps
        excerciseSets = Sets
        excerciseWeights = Weights
    }
    
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(excerciseName, forKey: "excerciseName")
        aCoder.encode(excerciseReps, forKey: "excerciseReps")
        aCoder.encode(excerciseSets, forKey: "excerciseSets")
        aCoder.encode(excerciseWeights, forKey: "excerciseWeights")
    }
    
    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let excerciseName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseName") as! String
        let excerciseReps = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseReps") as! String
        let excerciseSets = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseSets") as! String
        let excerciseWeights = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseWeights") as! String
        
        self.init(Name: excerciseName, Reps: excerciseReps, Sets: excerciseSets, Weights: excerciseWeights)
    }
    
}
```

In the view controller i want to access these variables in i have activated it:

```
var contacts = [Contact]()
```

My problem is when i am trying to access it it doesn't give me the option. when i type `self.contacts.` then nothing appears. i was expecting `self.contacts.excercises` to be there on auto fill. it that option isn't there. what am i missing?

Comment: `contacts` is an array and an array has no such property, you need a `for` loop or similar, for example `for contact in self.contacts { let exercises = contact.exercises...}`

Comment: Spot on thanks for that. i see now i was looking at the array itself. thanks